# CreateProcess with redirection access denied on the output pipe

Tags: winapi, pipe, createprocess

I have a simple code running in a DLL called from MFC application. Generally it implements the example that is shown in msdn article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx. Except I just want to create any process (say shell script). All the process creation is done fine with no errors. However, ReadFile with the output pipe always fails with error **5:Access is denied**. Making the same calls in a regular Win32 console application runs fine.

Please help.
-Ilya.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/1b401e3dea2897c0/0455a24f0e40b3a4#0455a24f0e40b3a4

Comment: The code is pretty much what the msdn example shows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonable answer at this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/1b401e3dea2897c0/0455a24f0e40b3a4?pli=1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.